# Dynamic html news page is not working in C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a dynamic news html page.
The problem occurs when I try to create the html dynamically. I'm new to C#, and don't know what's wrong. Here is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using NewsAPI;
using NewsAPI.Models;
using NewsAPI.Constants;

namespace NewsDemo
{
    public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadNewsPage();
            }
        }

        protected void LoadNewsPage()
        {
            try
            {
                var newsApiClient = new NewsApiClient("key");
                List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
                mylist.Add("google-news");
                mylist.Add("bbc-news");
                mylist.Add("cnn");
                mylist.Add("the-new-york-times");
                var articlesResponse = newsApiClient.GetTopHeadlines(new TopHeadlinesRequest
                {
                    Sources = mylist,
                    Language = Languages.EN
                });
                if (articlesResponse.Status == Statuses.Ok)
                {             
                    string resulHtml = "";
                    resulHtml += "<table>";
                    foreach (var article in articlesResponse.Articles)
                    {
                        resulHtml += string.Format("<tr style='valign:top'>", "");
                        resulHtml += string.Format("<td width=20%><img src='{0}' width='250px' height='200px'></img></td>", article.UrlToImage);
                        resulHtml += string.Format("<td width=80%><a href='{0}'><h3>{1}</h3></a>{1}<br>{2}<br>{3}<br><br></td>", article.Url, article.Title, article.Author, article.Description);

                        resulHtml += string.Format("</tr>", "");
                    }

                    resulHtml += string.Format("</table>", "");
                    Label1.Text = resulHtml;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run it, (in VS), Chrome opens and the page never loads. I have no idea what is wrong, as I have a console app that can fetch the news and that works fine.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on the opening bracket after `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`, does it ever get hit?

Comment: yes it does get hit

Comment: how did you get it to run?

Comment: how about the bracker after  `if (articlesResponse.Status == Statuses.Ok)` ? does it get hit?

Comment: well I did nothing special, I copied your code and used my own key to the service...

Comment: i don't think that it hits it

Comment: wonderful! add `var Result =articlesResponse.Status;` before `if (articlesResponse.Status == Statuses.Ok)` .what's its value?

Comment: in the if statement?

Comment: before it ;) let's see its value

Comment: https://gyazo.com/462be00c87902f2eedb3c0e389dbcca0

Comment: i meant the value of `var Result`...

Comment: How do I get that? I'm away from my computer right now. Will be back in 1hr

Comment: when the breakpoint gets hit, hover your mouse over the word "Result" and wait

Comment: It doesn't hit the breakpoint. I've narrowed it down to this, [see screenshot](https://gyazo.com/66b093afa72911242efc6aff14b82572). It hits the first breakpoint, but it's stuck from then on.

Comment: I got it by scraping the news directly from the JSON. It works now, yet it would be nice if the module just worked like it should. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Your comments to my answer helped my understand more.
I think your problem doesn't depend on your code but on a [known problem](https://www.johanbostrom.se/blog/how-to-disable-the-built-in-chrome-from-starting-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2017) with Chrome+Visual Studio

In short:

1. Either you can [debug with another browser](https://forums.asp.net/t/2119139.aspx?How%20I%20can%20change%20for%20the%20default%20browser%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202017%20)
2. Or you [disable JavaScript debugging](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21797/chrome-script-debugging-in-visual-studio-is-enable.html)

---

I tested your `LoadNewsPage()` and it does get HTML just fine.
What seems strange is that you are inserting the HTML into the text of a `Label`.

Instead of doing that, add this HTML in your markup:

```
<div id="MyNewsSection" runat="server"></div>
```

And then replace this

```
Label1.Text = resulHtml;
```

with

```
MyNewsSection.InnerHtml = resulHtml;
```

Also, as a general debugging help, press F12 when in Chrome: if there are any errors, they will be shown to you.

Comment: Great! I'm not home right now, but will test it when I get there.

Comment: But I still have the same problem.

Comment: the page refuses to load

Comment: What happens when you press f12 in chrome? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Ok, so the page just stays like this https://gyazo.com/abbfd61d1804696a63baf804a6ef45f4. I have left it for a least 1 hour before and it still didn't finish loading. When I press F12, I get this https://gyazo.com/463549157005d413c66fece49f44b72c, and this https://gyazo.com/463549157005d413c66fece49f44b72c

Comment: I have tried it in firefox, and edge. Still it doesn't finish loading

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup did you disable javascript debugging (solution .2)?

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup just follow this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21797/chrome-script-debugging-in-visual-studio-is-enable.html)

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup what happens if you comment this line `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`?